# Jar for different operating systems

Tags: java, linux, maven, jar, executable-jar

I created a project in java and made a jar.

I did this using maven on a Linux OS.

My problem is the jar compiles and works fine on Linux.

But when it comes to running it on windows it doesnt work really well. As in a jframe will appear but functions wont work.

I was looking at

```
 swtjar
```

But i hasnt been much help. Do jars not run on different os.

Can anyone point me in the right direction I have no idea why this is.
Thanks

edit  I get a NoClassDefFoundError for my gui

Comment: Properly implemented Java programs work across Operating Systems. Please post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: You have to bear in mind a bunch of operating systems details like file paths, etc.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with file paths. Heres the thing what would be wrong with say a file path like this 

"/images/image.png"
Using .class.getResource?

It works on Linux whats different about windows

Comment: Can whoever down-voted it please explain why? I dont know how else I would of asked the question?

Comment: @hat_to_the_back This is why things like `File.pathSeparator` exist.  So your code will be cross-platform compatible. Though, without seeing any of your code, it's difficult to guess as to what is mis-implemented.

Comment: @hat_to_the_back I didn't downvote your question, but I would bet that  the reason for it was that you haven't posted the stacktrace of the error you got, nor the code whence it was thrown.  Without being able to see what you're doing, it's virtually impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Linux = "/" and windows is "\" could that cause errors?

Comment: @azurefrog thanks for the advice I know for next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing Swing components and SWT widget together. Do not do that unless you have special reason. For SWT applications, it do have some difference between different OS as this is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

when you get a **NoClassDefFoundError** , there seems to be an problem with your classpath.
check if all files on classpath **really** exists.